# How to change the displayed formats of date attributes of files and folders in the file explorer (Windows 10)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I would like to change the **displayed** formats of date specific attributes (such as creation date, or last modified date) of folders and files inside folders I choose.

My goal is when opening a specific folder in "details" view and one of the properties that's shown is "creation date", the hour will be not displayed (essentially replacing the time format from "D/M/YYYY hh:mm" to "D/M/YYYY").

Is it possible to perform such action?

Comment: As far as I know you cannot change this.

Answer (score 2):

You can only change the date format for all of Windows, not for only one column
of Explorer.

This is done in *Control Panel > Region > Formats > Additional settings...*

It is really not a good idea to do so, as it will have an
unpredictable effect on other applications than Explorer.

For more details, see the article
[How to Set A Custom Date Format in Windows?](https://mywindowshub.com/how-to-set-a-custom-date-format-in-windows/)

Comment: I wonder what "unpredictable effects" are possible? The linked article doesn't say.